# download a zip file from a url

Tags: php, download, zip

I wanna use php to download some zip files from a url. I.E. sitename.com/path/to/file/id/123 when you go to this url directly you get a file download prompt. I've tried to use `fopen()` and `file_get_contents()` but these fail. The search I've done comeback with how to make a zip file downloadable or how to get the file from sitename.com/path/to/file.zip but my url doesn't have a .zip extension.

```
fopen ('url.com') or die('can not open');
```

The browser shows can not open

Comment: `but these fail.` what message did you get trying these methods? show the code, please.

Comment: should probably use `http://url.com` and if it's not dying but not showing try echoing

Comment: It is not enough. There could be a list of problems. Do you see any output (it will be weird without the right headers) or error message?   `echo file_get_contents('http://url.com/file');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The url is probably a script that may be redirecting you.  Use CURL instead

```
$fh = fopen('file.zip', 'w');
$ch = curl_init()
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // this will follow redirects
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: The zip file is downloading as an empty zip file. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: This answer doesn't work any more. It only creates an empty ZIP file.

Comment: If you get an empty file and on the server the zip works, then you probably need to set a content length. header("Content-Length: " . filesize($yourfile));

Comment: if someone also has the problem that only a part of the data is downloaded: GIVE MORE TIME! 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, (60*30)); // 30 minutes`
Also of course allow the script to run as long as it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to use the more basic functions like **[readfile()](http://php.net/readfile)** for this sort of thing.

Adapted from [an example at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a ZIP
header('Content-type: application/zip');

// Use Content-Disposition to force a save dialog.
// The file will be called "downloaded.zip"
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.zip"');

// The ZIP source is in original.zip
readfile('original.zip');
?>
```